# Eclipse 2021-06 update: Cant find my workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, package, explorer, workspace

All of my files of all my programs were all on the left side of my screen after opening Eclipse. After the 2021-06 update, I cant find them. I know they are there but its not easily accessible like it used to be (left side of screen). Does anyone know how to display all my workspace(packages, programs etc...) Hope this makes sense...thanks guys!

Comment: There was no change to how things are displayed in 2021-06. Possibly you have minimised the view - show us a picture.

Comment: Window menu > Show View menu item

Answer (score 1):

From the top bar:

```
Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective...
```

Comment: @Descode Then please accept the answer. I also know from others that [reseting the perspective fixes UI glitches that occur with a workspace that was last used with a very old version of Eclipse](https://twitter.com/j2r2b/status/1410450467285606403).